# Authentication across multiple domains

Tags: cross-domain, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I want to have an SSO for the following sites:

```
abc.com    
def.com
```

I read [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417) which has a very basic example on how to setup an SSO with master/slave domain setup. While it was a very good read it leaves some questions unanswered.

abc.com will be the master site that issues the auth cookie.

Say the user is not logged in on any site. If the site is abc.com, all i have to do is check for the auth cookie, no problem. If the user is on def.com, the example in the article redirects to abc.com and returns the cookie content (if any) as a query parameter in yet another redirect. If the cookie has content the cookie will be stored on def.com.

Issues:

1. Every page reload on def.com triggers 2 redirects if local cookie doesn't exist.
2. When user logs out, both master and slave cookies have to be deleted and also propagate to any other slave sites.
3. When the user logs in, I must make sure a cookie is set both on master and slave sites.

I am especially worried about point 1. Is there a way to get around this?

I thought of having the authentication all in ajax, but then i would need a page reload if an auth cookie is returned from abc.com to def.com. Not a very pleasing solution.

Does anyone have a better architecture altogether?

**EDIT**

Writing this down helped me out to at least to some extent solve the problem. If cookies are set for master + all slave sites at login, point 1 is no longer an issue.

The question is still open for anyone that want's to improve the solution.

Comment: Why are you trying to roll your own cross domain SSO protocol when there are robust solutions like SAML 2.0 available?